# MYSQL group by and count on JSON column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an sql table with json data like this

```
id  | int(11) Primary Key
reasons | json
```

On the json_data column i have arrays stored.

```
id| reasons

1 | ["price","inactive","small","other"]
2 | ["price","other"]
3 | ["price","inactive"]
```

I need to group by "reasons" and get the count

```
price | 3
inactive | 2
small | 1
other  | 2
```

I have tried this;

```
  $dealInvestors = Deal::select(
            "JSON_CONCAT(decline_reasons,'$.$all_possible_reasons)",
            'count(reasons) as count',
        )
            ->groupBy('reasons')
            ->get();
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? Does the upper limit of the values amount per JSON array exists?

Comment: @Akina I use mysql 8.0.19

Comment: Im not sure about the limits. How can i confirm that please?

Comment: Limit not needed for version 8+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT reason, COUNT(*)
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.reasons,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (reason VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')
                      ) jsontable
GROUP BY reason
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43cdbb8bfca8aa3cd3e82ccf775a577e

PS. I doubt that this query can be converted to Laravel syntax. Use raw SQL.